# How to make a cell?

Tags: animation, materials, node-editor, depth-of-field

I am realtively new to Blender. I want to make an animation of a cell, but I don't know how to set up the nodes for that. I would like to have a microscope-effect, with a prism-like refraction on parts of the cell (other cells in the background).

I found an old video that shows kind of what I want:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trbJWvu0D1A

But with nearly the same node set up in 2.8 (.blend file was in the description), it didn't work. Unlike in the video, I want to keep the color of the cell.

Here are some examples which can show what I want:
https://youtu.be/TTbS7_vZLNg
[image]
[image][image]
[image]

Thank you for your help. If somone has a good idea how to make the cell inside that would help, too.

Answer (score 4):

You can make texture from these images, using alpha for the outside of the cell.
After creating a mesh with sufficient subdivisions, make it like a lens and add caustics to it with cycles. (Render Settings -> Lightpath).
It may create this effect through regulation of the lens thick in the center.

This is cycles and a glass shader.
[image: img]

Comment: Coustics was already activated, and with a lens I was not able to find the wanted refraction :( I tried to make the lense with a glass shader and with a BSDF shader with highest transmission.

Comment: @Lothar I try to create this, as I understand: https://imgur.com/rtSuMRq this is cycles and glass material.

Comment: Thank you for creating this. The animation looks great. But the refraction I meant, is to split the light into spectral like colors depending on where the light comes from. I am sorry for bad explanation, I can't express myself that good in English.

Comment: @Lothar you may use color ramp with spectrum colors and separete normal from geometry node or camera data depend on wishes.

Comment: Okay, how can I separate normal from geometry?

Comment: @Lothar for get like this https://imgur.com/KR9TpQM I use this material setup https://imgur.com/oPXXzJl

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped a lot.

Comment: I tried to replicate your node setup, but it did not work https://imgur.com/a/mEVgGQc . Any ideas why? And why do you have less options for musgrave texture.

Comment: @Lothar you can download my file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tv28lv3mrwucyrk/backteria%20text%20from%20stack%20exchange1.blend?dl=0

Comment: Okay, I found my mistake. You have to look from the top, but my object was too thin. Thanks for sharing your file and all your help.

Comment: @Lothar thanks for answer!